# There is a free audio streaming software which can provide RTCP RR packets?

Tags: audio, streaming, voip

I want to test my voip system, but I cannot find a good software which can generate RTCP RR packets for statistics.

I already tried out these tools:

- **rtptools**: It is basically just stream a recorded pcap.
- **sipp**: Does the same, but you can make concurrent calls.
- **ffmpeg**: It is almost good, but the RTCP RR support only works with RTSP and the UDP RTSP is not working. I think it's a bug, because if I try to set stream with UDP it will starts to stream with TCP.
- **GStreamer**: Seems too complex to me and I feel it's not the best option to create such traffic.

This is my command for ffmpeg RTSP stream: `ffmpeg -loglevel repeat+level+trace -re -i input.mp3 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport udp rtsp://localhost:8554/live`. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but the logs shows clearly that the ffmpeg tries to make a TCP connection.

Also I found a lot of good and paid solutions, but I can't pay that amount of money.

I am also interested in any kind of library for any kind of programming language.

#### Edit:

I was able to run the `ffmpeg` command properly, but the `rtpengine` couldn't handle RTSP traffic.

Comment: Welcome ricsi!  Great question!  Upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of a learning curve but [Scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) is a python tool which can capture, generate & send literally any type of network traffic. This includes valid and invalid packets, any existing protocol and even protocols that don't yet exist.

So you should be able to generate *(interactively, programmatically and by replaying)* the traffic that you require, as well as a lot of other tricks to help with your testing and debugging.

The best bit is that it is free, gratis & open source, and available for a number of platforms.

Comment: Thank you very much. Meanwhile I found a solution what can generate such reports. I basically build up a whole voip system with Kamailio and Linphone, so I can generate a big load with ffmpeg and one with Linphone and it will generate rtcp rr. 
But in a longer run I will definitely build a better solution with Scapy, so I accept your answer.